# How to insert default values to foreign object with relation using Postgresql, Knex.js and Objection.js with HasOneRelation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I'm setting up simple API using `Postgresql`, `Knex.j`s and `Objection.js`. I created User model with "location" property. This "location" property is another table. How I have to insert that user to database with defaults 'city' and 'country' in 'location' property?

I already tried to use 'static get `jsonSchema`' in model itself and '`allowInsert`' method in mutation but when I fetching created that user the 'location' still 'null'.

So, let's say we have migration for users_table:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table
      .string('email')
      .unique()
      .notNullable();
    table.string('firstName').notNullable();
    table.string('lastName').notNullable();
    table.string('password').notNullable();
  });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('users');
```

And we have location_table:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable('locations', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('country').defaultTo('USA');
    table.string('city').defaultTo('San Francisco');
    table
      .integer('user_id')
      .references('id')
      .inTable('users')
      .onUpdate('CASCADE')
      .onDelete('CASCADE');
  });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('locations');
```

Here User Model with objection.js:

```
export default class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'users';
  }

  // wrong probably
  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        location: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            city: {
              type: 'string',
              default: 'Los Angeles',
            },
            country: {
              type: 'string',
              default: 'USA',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }

  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      location: {
        relation: Model.HasOneRelation,
        modelClass: Location,
        join: {
          from: 'users.id',
          to: 'locations.user_id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

And Location model:

```
export default class Location extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'locations';
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      user: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/User`,
        join: {
          from: 'locations.user_id',
          to: 'users.id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

My mutation when I creating new User:

```
// ...
const payload = {
      email,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      password: hash,
    };

    const newUser = await User.query()
      .allowInsert('[user, location]')
      .insertAndFetch(payload);
// ...
```

And in the end query:

```
// ...
User.query()
    .eager('location')
    .findOne({ email });
// ...
```

From query of user I expect to see the object with locatoin propety with my defaults. Example:

```
{
  email: 'jacklondon@gmail.com',
  firstName: 'Jack',
  fullName: 'Jack London',
  id: '1',
  lastName: 'London',
  location: {
    city: 'San Francisco',
    country: 'USA',
  },
  userName: 'jacklondon1',
  __typename: 'User',
}
```

So, where I made mistake with such simple operation?

Comment: `allowInsert` sets the allowed tree of relations to insert using `insertGraph` method. Nested relations are not available in `insertAndFetch` method. https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#insertgraph

Comment: If you suspect the `jsonSchema` is wrong, I would comment it out for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One to One Solution

I think part of the issue is that your allow insert included the `user` object. You shouldn't include the `user` in the allow insert because it's implicit since you're on the `User` model ([example](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#examples-2)). The other issue you had was that you were trying to use `insertAndFetch` method. `insertAndFetch` cannot be used when inserting a graph. You need to use the `insertGraph` method to insert a graph ([docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#insertgraph)). Since you are using Postgres, you can chain the `returning(*)` method and it will return the result without additional queries ([example](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#insertgraphandfetch)). Finally, since you're asking for a one-to-one relation, you have to specify a city and country every time. Objection will not know it needs to create a new row without specifying it (even if you have configured the database to have default values). The way I accomplished this for you was to use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```
const createNewuser = async (email, firstName, lastName, hash, city = 'Los Angeles', country = 'USA') => {   

  const newUser = await User
    .query()
    .insertGraph({
      email,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      password: hash,
      location: {
        city: city,
        country: country
      }
    })
    .returning('*');

   return newUser;
}
```

#### Additional Thought to Ponder

I'm not sure why you have a one-to-one relationship between user and location. Why not just make city, state, and country part of the user's table since it's already one to one?

However, what I think you're really going for is a one-to-many relationship between user and location. One location has multiple users. This would put you into [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) by reducing the amount of duplicate data in your database since you wouldn't duplicate a city/country for each user in an identical location.

If you're just learning objection, I would recommend reading up on graphs in the [documentation](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#graph-inserts).